# Calling WCF Service Operation in multithreaded Console Application

Tags: multithreading, wcf, c#-3.0

I have below application:

1. Its windows console .NET 3.0 application
2. I'm creating 20 workloads and assigning them to threadpool to process.
3. Each thread in ThreadPool creates WCF Client and calls service with request created using workload assigned.

Sometimes on production servers[12 core machines], I get following exception:

There was an error reflecting type 'xyz' while invoking operation using WCF client. This starts appearing in all threads. After sometime it suddenly disappears and starts appearing again.

Code:

Pseudo Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{

MultiThreadedProcess proc =new MultThreadedProcess(someData[i]);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(proc.CallBack,i);

}
```

In Class MultiThreadedProcess, I do something like this:

```
public void Callback(object index)
{

MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
MyServiceResponse response =client.SomeOperation(new MyServiceRequest(proc.SomeData));
client.close();
//Process Response
}
```

Can anyone suggest some resolutions for this problem?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating WCF client instance and invoking operation? Also make sure you call close method, when done and where required.

Comment: Yes. I do close the WCF client

Comment: Also mention SomeOperation signature/attributes and SomeData declaration

Answer (score 0):

If you can turn on diagnostic, appears to me serialization issue, there might be chance that certain data members/values are not able to de-serialized properly for operation call.

Comment: Shouldn't this happen for every call then? It happens sometimes and only on 12 core machines.

Comment: Is there any particular scenario that you have executed on your machine and it runs and doesn't run on 12 core?